# Reversible program

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, source-layout

#### Objective

Write a program that outputs some printable ASCII characters. The trick is that if the program is reversed byte-by-byte, it must output the same thing in the reverse order, byte-by-byte, too.

#### Rules

- No standard loopholes.
- The program must **not** be a palindrome, nor can it be 1 byte in length (or empty). No restriction for patterns of the output as long as:
- The output is at least 2 bytes long. It must contain solely printable ASCII characters, including visible characters and newlines, tabs and spaces. It should not be empty.
- **Outputs to standard error is ignored.**
- **Quine programs are forbidden.**

  For example, the following program makes no sense (HQ9+)

  ```
  AQ
  ```

#### Easy Mode

Paired parentheses/brackets/curly brackets are swapped after reversing source, so a reverse may be:

```
print("Hello");
;("olleH")tnirp  # not ;)"olleH"(tnirp
```

**Make a note in your answer** if your program uses this "Easy Mode".

#### Example

These are theoretical examples and may not exist in any programming language.

```
input -> output

program -> abcd
margorp -> dcba

() -> 10
)( -> 01

print('yes')tnirp -> yes
print('sey')tnirp -> sey
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the program with the shortest source code (in bytes) in each language wins!

### Leaderboard

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 142801; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 48934; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    if (/<a/.test(lang)) lang = jQuery(lang).text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang > b.lang) return 1;
    if (a.lang < b.lang) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Winners by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Surely any `cat`-like language can do this in 2 bytes?

Comment: Better description for that last rule should be "Your source should not be a quine". Also, a clear example would be nice.

Comment: @Neil Good point. It's forbidden now.

Comment: @iBug I think you should try sandbox next time. I feel that you just wanted to post your answer without taking sometime to think about other peoples answers (like quines). Also it is not nice to change the rules after 12 answers have been posted...

Comment: I see this put on hold but I do not see any comments about how this question can be improved. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: I don't understand the last test case -- shouldn't it be `sey` output for the second part?

Comment: Why is this challenge still getting downvoted? Please leave a comment if you think this challenge can be improved.

Answer (score 8):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 2 bytes

```
Ai
```

Forwards, produces `ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA`, backwards, produces `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`.

`A` pushes the alphabet, and `i` reverses it, although if `i` doesn't have anything to reverse, it conveniently does nothing.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/98x8/9/AA)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
22«33
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/I6NBqY@P//wE)

The first is `min(22, 33)` and the reverse is `min(33, 22)`

## Also 5 bytes

```
.)25½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/19P08j00N7//wE)

The `)` seems to discard everything before it. This is `sqrt(25)` which is `5.0` and the reverse is `.` which is `0.5`.

Comment: +1 for the `5.0` vs. `0.5`.

Comment: `The program must not be a palindrome, nor can it be 1 byte in length (or empty). No restriction for patterns of the output as long as:`

Answer (score 3):

## Excel VBA, 11 Bytes

*(Ab)uses the fact that Excel has more than one STDOUT; Does not use Easy Mode*

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs `12` to the VBE immediate window.

```
?12'12=]1A[
```

#### Reversed

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs `21` to the the range `[A1]` on the ActiveSheet Object.

```
[A1]=21'21?
```

Note: `?12'12?` works as well but feels a bit too close to palindromic to be within the spirit of the challenge

Comment: shouldn't [A1] be reversed to [1A]?

Comment: @Jenny_mathy Yep it should - and now it is

Answer (score 3):

## Brain-Flak, <s>35</s> 28+1=29 bytes

```
((#)}{))
()()()()(
 )){})#((
```

1 extra byte because of the flag `-A` to print ascii. This prints "\n\n"

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0NDWbO2WlOTS0MTCrkUNDWrazWVNTT@//@v6wgA)

-6 bytes thanks to [Riley](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/57100/riley) pointing out that I can cleverly use newlines in order to not duplicate as much code for the reversed program. This works because the pound sign only starts a single line comment.

Comment: When reversed, this does not produce the output reversed.

Comment: @ATaco fixed...

Comment: Seems to print a space and a newline at the TIO link you provided.

Comment: @JonathanAllan For some reason I thought 32 was a newline yesterday. Fixed to use 10 instead.

Comment: Saved quite a few bytes from that :D

Comment: Combining this with [Funky Computer Man's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142827/57100) you can get to [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0NDWbO2WlOTS0MTCrkUNDWrazWVNTT@//@v61gEAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Rain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>65</s> 59 bytes

```
((((((#)])([))(}{)}{))}{))
()()()()(
)){})){}){})())#((((((
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XwMMlDVjNTWiNTU1aqs1gQiMuTQ0oZBLU7O6FoyBSENTUxmi6f///7qORQA)

This pushes

```
()
```

going forwards and

```
)(
```

going backwards.

It needs to pad the front with a newline because Brain-Flak's output automatically gets a newline added to the end of the output.

Comment: The language changed its name too?

Comment: @JonathanAllan That is the (informal) name of the Ruby interpreter of the language.

Comment: @JonathanAllan What Erik said is correct.  The comment behavior used here is unique to the Ruby interpreter so I specified the interpreter as to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
0%
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99A9f9/AA)** ...or **[try `%0`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/V4P9/AA)**

Both full programs output the palindromic `nan` as they both attempt to take a modulo of zero by zero and implicitly print the result.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 5 bytes

```
44+55
```

or...

## Mathematica, 4 bytes

```
11*9
```

outputs `99`

Comment: The last one is no longer allowed. Quines are forbidden.

Comment: @iBug I think you should try sandbox next time. I feel that you just wanted to post your answer without taking sometime to think about other peoples answers (like quines). Also it is not nice to change the rules after 12 answers have been posted...

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), 4 bytes

```
"Jj"
```

Outputs [`Jj`](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%22Jj%22&debug=0) and [`jJ`](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%22jJ%22&debug=0) when reversed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>43</s> <s>42</s> 52 bytes

#### Source

```python
#1.,"n\"tnirp:tpecxe
#"""
print"\n",\
1.#"""cexe:yrt
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/X9lQT0cpL0apJC@zqMCqpCA1uSKVS1lJSYmroCgzr0QpJk9JJ4bLUA8klJxakWpVWVTy/z8A)

#### Reversed source

```python
try:exec"""#.1
\,"n\"tnirp
"""#
except:print"\n",.1#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6So0iq1IjVZSUlJWc@QK0ZHKS9GqSQvs6iACyTElVqRnFpQYlVQlJlXohSTp6SjZ6j8/z8A)

---

Inspired by [i cri everytim's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142823/73111). Does, however, not require 'easy mode'.

The program's outputs now are true reverses of one another, not ignoring the new line character. Thanks to [@Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan) for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>4</s> 3 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @ETHproductions*

#### Normal

```
12C
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=MTJD&input=) Prints `12`.

#### Reversed

```
C21
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=QzIx&input=) Prints `21`.

Only the last statement is printed, and `C` is the constant for `12`.

Comment: Don't think you even need the `;`, do you?

Comment: @ETHproductions Right, I don't. I had been trying to implement using `;` as the first char before coming to this one.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
1+³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99Q@9Dm//8B)

This is `1 + 100` which is `101`. The reverse is just `100 + 1` which is also `101`. Replacing `+` with `_` works too.

## Also 3 bytes

```
11»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/Q8NDu//8B)

The first is `max(11, 0)`. The reverse is just `max(0, 11)`. The argument is `0` by default if not present.

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>67</s> <s>23</s> 21 bytes

- Saved two bytes thanks to [12Me21](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64538/12me21); using a tab instead of a new line.

```
+++++++++..+++++++++>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwb09OBMu///AQ)

The program's ouput are two <s>spaces</s> <s>new lines</s> tabs. It is nearly a palindrome, apart from the trailing or leading cell shift (`>`).

Comment: Using tab (character 9) would save 2 more bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://perl.org) / [Perl 6](https://perl6.org) / [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 17 bytes

```perl6
print 12#12 tnirp
```

[Try it in Perl 5](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRMHQSNnQSKEkL7Oo4P9/AA)
[Try it reversed in Perl 5](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRMHIUNnIUKEkL7Oo4P9/AA)

[Try it in Perl 6](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/7@gKDOvRMHQSNnQSKEkL7Oo4P9/AA)
[Try it reversed in Perl 6](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/7@gKDOvRMHIUNnIUKEkL7Oo4P9/AA)

[Try it in Ruby](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6AoM69EwdBI2dBIoSQvs6jg/38A)
[Try it reversed in Ruby](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6AoM69EwchQ2chQoSQvs6jg/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 20 bytes

```python
print'\n';#'n\'tnirp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EPSZP3VpZPS9GvSQvs6jg/38A)

`print'\n'` prints both the single newline it instructs and an implicit newline after.

`print'\n';` does exactly the same - the `;` is just there to stop the program being a palindrome.

The `#` marks the start of a comment.

Comment: [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EwdDIWtnIUKEkL7Oo4P9/AA) if you return a number instead of a string -> if the implicit newline counts you could save even 2 more bytes from that answere. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Simon `print 12;` does not "return a number" it prints a string representation of the number. The implicit newline needs to be a part of the reversed output, so you'd need to ``print'\n'+`12`;#...``

Comment: ...we could have `print'';#''tnirp` if it were not for the specification: "The output is at least 2 bytes long".

Comment: Okay, I did read that reverse specification wrong.Would `print 1;#'1n\'tnirp`work?

Comment: @Simon forwards that outputs `1\n` and in reverse it outputs `\n1\n`.

Comment: Allright. I think its too late right now. I should stop trying to think of something else.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 2 bytes

Both output `11`. `B` is the Japt constant for `11` and the `w` method, when applied to a number, returns the larger of that number and any number passed to it as an argument.

```
wB
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=d0I=&input=)

```
Bw
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=Qnc=&input=)

Answer (score 1):

### Charcoal, 2 bytes

```
-¹
```

The `-` is simply a string literal that implicitly prints itself. The `¹` is a numeric literal, and the default is to implicitly print one `-` too. Any ASCII character and non-zero Unicode superscript would work.

```
²←
```

Forwards, this prints two `-`s, then moves the cursor back one step (but this does not affect the output). Backwards, this prints two `-`s leftwards, but the output remains the same. Any subscript from 2 to 9 would work here, as would a right arrow or the reflect operator `‖`.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 132 bytes

Dang full program requirements..

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print("OK");}}//}};)"OK"(tnirp.tuo.metsyS{)a][gnirtS(niam diov citats{M ecafretni
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##FY1BCsMgEAC/IjnpoeYBeUIJPXgMOSxmEzZFDboRgvh2a48zMMwJGV7hQn9u39bIM8YdLIq5JAYmK3KgTTggLw1H8seygirmSYxOh5v11SXL4fMe1FTrONY6qT9J9hQvzXfQDjk9pihYl6NLNtITOLFRyMJS36QyC7SwR@xRaz8) Prints `OK`.

Reversed:

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print("KO");}}//}};)"KO"(tnirp.tuo.metsyS{)a][gnirtS(niam diov citats{M ecafretni
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##FY1BCsMgEAC/IjnpoeYBeUIJPXgMOSxmEzZFDboRgvh2a48zMMwJGV7hQn9u39bIM8YdLIq5JAYmK3KgTTggLw1H8seygirmSYxOh5v11SXL4f0Z1FTrONY6qT9J9hQvzXfQDjk9pihYl6NLNtITOLFRyMJS36QyC7SwR@xRaz8) Prints `KO`.

Comment: Hey! I said "make a note" if you're using the *Easy Mode* rule.

Comment: @iBug Oops.. misread that part. Roll-backed to my initial version. I edited on purpose so it wasn't the easy mode anymore; but apparently I've edited into the easy mode instead.. My initial answer was already not the easy mode.. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
?RA?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fPsjR/v9/AA) or [Try it reversed!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f3jHI/v9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), 12 bytes

```js
_=>12//12>=_
```

Reversed:

```js
_=>21//21>=_
```

Code snippet:

```js
a=_=>12//12>=_
b=_=>21//21>=_
console.log(a())
console.log(b())
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 2 bytes

```
γδ
```

Outputs 12. Reversed, outputs 21.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//9zmc1v@/wcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), 6 bytes

```
%.%%%%
```

Prints `000`. Triangle looks like this:

```
  % 
 . % 
% % %
```

Reversed triangle looks like this:

```
  % 
 % % 
% . %
```

The IP starts travelling southeast from the topmost character, so in both triangles `%%%` is interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 4 bytes

```
?12?
```

This will work in many BASIC dialects.

Prints "12" forwards, and "21" backwards.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 16 bytes

```
printf 12 ftnirp
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhYbCooy80rSFAyNFNJK8jKLCiDCUFmYKgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS), 2 bytes

```
À\
```

Same as the winning RProgN 2 answer. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@//9wQ8z//wA)

### You can use a [tool](https://tio.run/##HcqxCsIwFIbR3af4u7WDFucufZWQ@0GDJim5wdFXj8XxwPGUzzfeQ3yNMX8fy3ab7899W8agdJq8ZhSroYOGQjE5KHU1PjTHpnWdDP9TPQlcVoKufgirUeTqV@@FHw) in this language to print the reverse of your code.

Answer (score 0):

## [Cubically 2.1](//github.com/aaronryank/cubically/releases/v2.1), 5 bytes

```
%0%1%
```

Prints `09`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5NykxOzMmp/P9f1UDVUPX///8A) or [Try it reversed!](https://tio.run/##Sy5NykxOzMmp/P9f1VDVQPX///8A)

The top (0-indexed) face is initialized to 0 and the left (1-indexed) face is initialized to 9. So printing (`%`) 0 prints 0 and printing 1 prints 9.

No longer works in Cubically 2.2 as `%` can be called implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

## [shortC](//git.io/shortC), 18 bytes

```
AJ"hi")}//})"hi"JA
```

Prints `hi`. Exploits comments. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87ILypJ/v/f0UspI1NJs1Zfv1YTxPJy/P//PwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [rk](//github.com/aaronryank/rk-lang), 50 bytes

```
rk:start
dne:kr
print: "hi" :tnirp
trats:kr
rk:end
```

Reversed via [this tool](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@/1@jTk/TmktD19DBWvP//6JsK6B4UQlXSl6qVXYRV0FRZl6JlYJSRqaSglVJXmZRAVdJUWJJMUgOqDY1LwUA):

```
dne:kr
rk:start
print: "ih" :tnirp
rk:end
trats:kr
```

rk ignores everything before `rk:start` and `rk:end`. Of course, it ignores everything in the middle it doesn't understand anyway.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCgAgCATAu6@QnuFvgoJEkNj2/1bnGUQVwg47KCOnBWTDk6ZteVNjOrYQnefbuzNH1QU) vs [Try it reversed!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCgAgCATAu6@QnuFvgoJEkNj2/1bnGUTVyGkBQdhhB2XDk6bNV1NjOva3mUOIzvNu1QU)

Answer (score -1):

### Unix sh, 15 bytes

```
echo ab#ab ohce
```

Reversed:

```
echo ba#ba ohce
```

Outputs `ab` and `ba`, respectively.

Comment: I don't know what shell you're using, but this outputs `ab#ab ohce` in every shell I've tried. (because `#` only starts a comment after a space)

Answer (score -3):

### [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 3 bytes

```
1
0
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/9@Ay/D/fwA)

---

Reversed source:

```
0
1
```

Reversed output:

```
1
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/9@Ay/D/fwA)

Comment: at least give other people a chance to answer your challenge before you post your own answers

Comment: Is this the only thing anyone knows about RProgN2? It's a rather powerful language >:I

Comment: @ATaco Yes. Someone else posted this twice on my questions, so it's the only program I can write.

Comment: Well it [Has a tutorial](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2/wiki/Tutorial) if you ever feel like learning more about it! :P